# Replacing the last item inside of some nested lists with each consecutive item of another list

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the last byte of each nested list in `redChannelListBinaryList` with each consecutive byte from `text2Binary3`, but I can't get it to work.

```
text2Binary3 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

redChannelListBinaryList = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
[redChannelListBinaryList[n].pop(-1) for n in range(18)]
print(redChannelListBinaryList)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What I want:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], ..., [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: OK... I think I've fixed the question so that SO won't block from asking questions. Let's hope this one gets at the very least voted up to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this. Added two line in your existing code

```
text2Binary3 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

redChannelListBinaryList = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
[redChannelListBinaryList[n].pop(-1) for n in range(18)]
for i,j in zip(redChannelListBinaryList,text2Binary3 ):
    i.append(j)
```

You have deleted the last element but not appended the new one you want to add from your `text2Binary3` list